# How to run jhbuild as root

Tags: gnome, python, root, gtk3, jhbuild

I have installed jhbuild and set the PATH variable to $PATH:~/.local/bin. Now when I run jhbuild command I get error: **You should not use jhbuild as root user** and when I change the user to non-root and again I change the PATH value to above one replacing ~ with /root, I get error **jhbuild command not found.**
I am using kali linux so the default user is root user.

Comment: This is probably a permission issue, can you edit and add the output of this command `ls -la /root`   (The user don't have the right to see what is inside /root, so it will not find the command)

Comment: @Félicien   Now I can execute jhbuild command but I it gives me error jhbuild: install prefix (/jhbuild/install) can not be created

Comment: Still seems to be a  permission issue. Is there a reason you installed it in /root ? a solution would be to move it to /opt and change the ownership of the directory (and below)  to the user you want to use

Comment: @Félicien you are right I changed the permissions, now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution **for command not found** I changed the permissions of the directory from where shell is looking for command(/root/.local/bin) and all the files which jhbuild wants to create from the command(e.g. /jhbuild,/jhbuild/.cache). I create them manually and changed their permissions in similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you're experiencing is unrelated to permissions or the location of the binary, but to the user executing it. Specify the environment variable `JHBUILD_RUN_AS_ROOT` with any value, e.g. `env JHBUILD_RUN_AS_ROOT= jhbuild ...` in order to be able to run `jhbuild` as root.

This is a rather undocumented feature, I'm sure I suggested an improvement of the application feedback once which has been ignored; see https://github.com/GNOME/jhbuild/blob/master/jhbuild/main.py#L97 for an idea why this should work.

Comment: Thanks but this is old post and now I changed the disto, so I am unable to verify anything.

Answer (score 0):

As Karl Richter said you need to use `env JHBUILD_RUN_AS_ROOT= jhbuild ...` in order to be able to run `jhbuild` as root.

Because they put a root check https://github.com/GNOME/jhbuild/blob/master/jhbuild/main.py#L59, if the user that is running it is root you get that error.

That solution is fine when you update or build the modules.
But if you want to run a version of gnome that you have built you won't be able and get that error again.
I saw it on the logs.

So you need to remove the root check from the `jhbuild` files.
After you won't need to set the `env` and you can just use `jhbuild ...`.

### How build `jhbuild` package removing root check:

1. Kali is based on Debian so you can use `apt source jhbuild`.
2. Remove the root check from `jhbuild-<version>/jhbuild/main-py`.
   Lines to remove (or comment):

> ```
> if 'JHBUILD_RUN_AS_ROOT' not in os.environ and hasattr(os, 'getuid') and os.getuid() == 0:
>     uprint(_('You should not run jhbuild as root.\n'), file=sys.stderr)
>     sys.exit(1)
> ```

3. Install the required packages to build it: `apt build-dep jhbuild`.
4. Install the created `.deb` file in the parent
   directory: `dpkg -i *.deb`.

For `command not found` you can install `jhbuild` with `apt` so it will be available system wide.
Or build it again for each users, or as you said fix the permissions.